# Going through a list

Tags: python, list

Say you have a list [1,2,3,4]
And I want to get [2,3,4,1] or [3,4,1,2].
Basically I am using the list with a different starting point each time, but then continuing through the list. How would I create something to recognize that in python.

What i have now is list[n:] where n is the shifted value, say 2, making you start at three.

Comment: What are you trying to recognize?

Answer (score 3):

```
someList[n:] + someList[:n]
```

would solve your purpose `if n <= len(someList)`

Also, `collections.deque` is the efficient way.

Comment: Assuming `n < len(yourlist)`.  Also, please [don't use `l` as a name here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid)

Comment: Thanks, +1.  Also, you could just use `n %= len(someList)` first.

Comment: Yes. Why not ! But, as it is your suggestion, please go ahead and edit the code with your contribution :) There is no reason that I should take credit for it

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you want

```
>>> def startAt(index, list):
...     print list[index:] + list[:index]
... 
>>> l = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> startAt(3, l)
[3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2]
>>>
```